# Any important things to keep in mind while configuring log4net in web farm asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net, web-farm, web-farm-framework

We are implementing a brand new web site application. For logging we have opted for log4net dll approach. We are going to launch the websites in  web farm framework. So we are using 4 servers for launching our websites, via a load balancer.

Is there anything I should keep in mind, especially with log4net (because I am going to work in that particular part) while hosting the application in web farm..

Thanks and Regards,
cmr.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to keep in mind is where are your log entries going to be stored and how you intend to consult them. It is clear that if you opt to store log entries in text files, when you are running in a web farm, searching in those files might be challenging as you will need to aggregate the information from all your nodes. In this case you may consider centralizing your log entries in some common storage like a SQL database or ElasticSearch as it will make searching a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks, How about storing in flat file and reading it via sumo logic I will be saving all logs in d: drive